# i2p Сеть: ОШИБКА — Симметричный NAT

Tags: linux, debian, nat

Debian, поставил i2p, в Консоле маршрутизатора, вроде всё работает кроме "Сеть: ОШИБКА — Симметричный NAT" .
Подскажите как в консоли i2p сделать чтобы было OK, вместо ошибки.

Гуглил данную проблему, но на удивление ничего не нашел. Или как обычно, нужно пару часов включенным подержать маршрутизатор i2p и всё само настроится?